# What user account does IIS 8.5 use when the app pool is using 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'?

Tags: php, windows, iis, joomla

I am working with a new Windows 2012 R2 server, running IIS 8.5.  I have PHP and a Joomla site installed in the default wwwroot folder for testing purposes (C:\inetpub\wwwroot).

Right now, the default web site is using the 'Default Web Site' application pool which in turn is using the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' identity.

The Joomla site loads without issue, but problems start appearing when it needs to write to the file system (i.e. new modules, changes to the configuration file, etc.).  The logs indicate that the system does not have permission to write to the file system.

I have applied various different combinations of write / modify / full permissions for different user accounts including the 'IIS AppPool\Default Web Site' , 'IUSR', and 'IIS_IUSRS' group.  None of these correct the issue.  However, if I have assign full access to the wwwroot folder to 'Everyone', all of the functionality works as expected.

Now, obviously that is less than ideal, so what user account is IIS / PHP using in this case that I can grant specific NTFS permissions to rather than opening the file system up to the world?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When adding the name, be sure to select your local server's name, not the domain name. I couldn't figure out why the name wasn't resolving and this was why:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Grant permission to following account:

IIS AppPool\'your identity pool name'. Emaple: If your Application Pool identity name is .NET v4.5 then,

Grant permission to IIS AppPool.Net v4.5