# php unlink on windows fails (permission denied), rename works

Tags: php, windows, iis, permissions

I have iis8.5 and php 7.1 (fastcgi, says phpinfo). I'm trying to unlink (delete) a folder.

```
unlink(realpath($folder));
```

and get a permission denied. If I try

```
exec(sprintf("rd /s /q %s", escapeshellarg($folder)));
```

it still doesn't work, but I don't get a reason either. So its permissions then - ok.

If I do a `get_current_user()` in the script it returns `IUSR`.

In IIS I have the app pool identity of the site to a user who has FULL CONTROL on the parent of the folder I'm trying to remove. `IUSR` also has FULL CONTROL of the same folder (and read from the root down to there, obviously).

Not sure what the permissions have to be in order for php to have delete capability. Many many SO answers simply say "you have to have the correct permissions" or "make sure you set the correct permissions". *grumble*

What are the permissions I need to add and where do I do that to make `unlink` or `rmdir` work?

Comment: My solution (e.g. *awful hack*) is to `rename` the folder out to a temporary location (e.g. c:\temp) and delete it from there by hand. It's not deleted, but it's also gone from where I want. I hate IIS.

Answer (score -1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

"Giving a user permission to write to a file but not to delete it doesn't prevent the user from deleting the file's contents. A user can still delete the contents." Write will let you empty the file but not remove it.

You'll need "Full Modify" or "Execute" to delete the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398834/can-do-php-write-or-copy-on-mounted-remote-share-but-not-an-unlink-or-re#comment75797738_44398834

Comment: Permission are already set to FULL CONTROL. That' every permission Windows can add, which includes FULL MODIFY and EXECUTE and DELETE. The linked articles don't tell me which user should have these permissions.

Comment: Whichever user you have IIS configured to run as.

Comment: I've set the user named `IIS` to have full control, and the group named `IIS_IUSRS` to have full control. The web site has an app pool which has a user set on it, and I've set *that* user to have full control. The files still won't unlink because of a permission problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990316/what-user-account-does-iis-8-5-use-when-the-app-pool-is-using-applicationpoolid suggests it should work; it doesnt; /frustrating!